# Can an Insert/update followed by a select (nolock) yield unexpected results with same data?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, nolock

In a stored procedure,

can an insert/update followed by a select (nolock) on the same record yield unexpected results?

Do I always get the (complete) updated/inserted record?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Why would you use a `NOLOCK` hint if you care?

Comment: Prevent (b)locks, but we notice some weird results once awhile. There are a lot of concurrent threads, all operating on a unique record (new or updated)

Comment: Concurrent insert/update activity during a NOLOCK scan can cause rows to be missed or duplicated.  It would be better to turn on the READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT database option unless your application relies on pessimistic locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If everything is done by single process, then data will be correct.
But if the stored procedure is called from a different process id and user is doing select (nolock) in other process then discrepancy in data can happen for select.

As stored procedure may be still in use.

Comment: Thx Signh! There are a lot of concurrent threads, all operating on a unique record (new or updated). Still no problem?

Comment: Ideally nolock and read uncommitted should not be used but if you plotting your result set to a graph or to dashboard and you can afford some discrepancy as they are showing treads then you may use nolock.